# How to check whether a path of given weight exists in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

A weighted nonoriented graph is given, check if there is a path of weight k between vertices 1 and n.

Looks like an NP-problem, but I am asked to check it under 2 seconds, K is <= 10^18.
We can use every road as many times as we want.
Would be grateful for any help.

N and M are pretty small(<=50), so i consider using dp for paths of weight up to k.
N,M,K are integers, weights of edges are < 10^4. The graph may be not connected
This problem is from codeforces training, unfortunately, the statement is not in English, so there won't be any use in attaching the statement.

> There is a country with n cities, cities have numbers 1 to n, all the roads both directed. Every road connects two cities.
>
> Mr Walker really enjoys walking. Moving along any road in any direction takes w(i) minutes. Mr Walker doesn't stay at cities and as soon as he reaches one city he immediately goes to another one
>
> Mr Walker starts at the city with number 1 and wants to reach n-th city in exactly K minutes. You need to check whether it is possible or not.
>
> Input - first line contains two integers n, m (1 ≤ n, m ≤ 50). Next m lines describe roads a(i) - start, b(i) - end, d(i) - time required to go all along the road (1 ≤ ai, bi ≤ n; 1 ≤ di ≤ 10^4).
>
> Last line contains a number k - time Mr Walker would like his path to take (1 ≤ t ≤ 10^18).
>
> Print Possible if is so and Impossible if Mr Walker wouldn't be able to reach n-th city in exactly k minutes.

Comment: Check out the implementation of A*-Algorithm. It searches for the shortest route in a graph. try to optimize it, since u don't need the actual path, but only a boolean

Comment: @legacy, that is not going to work. This is not about shortest path.

Comment: Are the weights integers? Are there negative weights?

Comment: Is this an online judge question ? Can you provide a link to the original statement ?

Comment: Can you give the exact problem statement? Do we know anything about M and N other than that they're small. Do we know if the graph is connected?

Comment: Possibly related https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30106/finding-an-exactly-weighted-st-path-in-a-digraph

Comment: Did you mean 104 to be 10^4, and 1018 to be 10^18?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the online judge so that we can validate our answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can do matrix exponentiation of the weighted adjacency matrix to compute all possible path weights of the paths that have length *k*. This takes *O(n<sup>3</sup> log(k))* time. Assuming there are no negative weights, all entries in matrix *M<sup>k</sup>* are bigger than or equal to those in *M<sup>k-1</sup>*.

Now if a path of weight *K* exists we can assume that it must have some finite length *k'*. We can do a binary search for *k'* using the topleft most element from our matrix exponentiation. The result from this is either a valid *k'* that gives us *K* in the topleft corner, meaning we are done, we found a solution, or the binary search tells us that no such *k'* exists, so we can eliminate the top left corner.

You do that for each position in the matrix, and you either eliminate them all or find a solution. Total complexity is *O(n<sup>5</sup> log(k'))*, which isn't great, but it's an algorithm.